# Afraime component setting World Position of Child element

Tags: aframe

I have a parent aframe component. It creates some child aframe component. So the parent aframe component's position is setting static in world hub, but child's position is dynamic. They are moving with camera move/or when on fly mode is on. I don't know how to fix it. If I append the child component directly to the "a-scene" Position will become static. Why the child append has dynamic position, I don't know(

```
AFRAME.registerComponent("parent-element", {
 init(){
 this.el.object3D.position.set(x, y, z)
  const childeEL= document.createElement("a-entity");
          childeEL.setAttribute("id", "child-id")
          childeEL.setAttribute("is-remote-hover-target", "");
          childeEL.setAttribute("tags", "singleActionButton:true");
          childeEL.setAttribute("sprite", "name: child.png");
          childeEL.setAttribute("scale", "3 3 3");
          childeEL.setAttribute("billboard", "onlyY: false");
          childeEL.setAttribute("child-component", {
            position: this.data.position
          })          
        this.el.appendChild(childeEL)
 }
)}

AFRAME.registerComponent("child-element", {
  schema: {
    position: { vec: "" }
 }, 
init(){
  this.el.object3D.position.set(this.data.x, this.data.y, this.data.z)
}
)}
```

I tried to append the child element to directly a-scen. It worked, but it is not a solution what I am trying to find

Comment: is the `[parent-element]` moving with the camera?

Comment: @PiotrAdamMilewski yes. My parent-element just change rotation with the camera. It doesn't change position. Always looks by camera direction. Is it the main problem?

Comment: @PiotrAdamMilewski I think I've found the solution or temp fix.  I commented out this line `//parent-elemnt.setAttribute("billboard", "onlyY: false")` and my **parent-element** stopped rotation and **children-element** also.